# Expanding $1/z$ about $z=-1$ using Taylor series vs Power Series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I need to expand $1/z$ about $z_0=-1$. I decided to do it using both methods, which don't agree.

**Using Taylor:** Finding coefficients:
$$f^{(n)}(z)=(-1)^n n!/z^{n+1} \Rightarrow f^{(n)}(-1)=-n!$$
Pluggin into taylor series formula:

$$\frac{1}{z}=\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(-1)}{n!}(z+1)^n=\sum -(z+1)^n$$

On the other hand **using Power Series** I get:

$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{z+1-1}=\frac{1}{z+1}\frac{1}{1-1/(z+1)}=\frac{1}{z+1}\sum \frac{1}{(z+1)}^n=\sum \frac{1}{(z+1)^{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why didn't you do the following?:

$$\frac1z=\frac1{z+1-1}=-\frac1{1-(z+1)}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(z+1)^n$$

and you get the same as with the Taylor series, derivatives and etc.

This is valid whenever $\;|z+1|<1\;$ , which is what you want (I presume)...and in your power series method you can't use this geometric series development since

$$\frac1{|z+1|}<1\iff|z+1|>1\;$$

which is *not* (I presume) what you want.

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to expand taylor series for $|x+1|>1$?

Comment: @GRS Then you do what you did and you get, of course, a Laurent expansion as you're leaving the disk $\;|z+1|\le1\;$ off bounds.

Comment: but if I taylor expand I get: $\sum -\frac{1}{x+1}^n \ne \sum \frac{1}{x+1}^{n+1}$

Comment: @GRS I don't follow: what Taylor expansion are you talking about? This one exists if the function is *analytic*, but in your case it wouldn't be in that domain $\;|z+1|>1\;$ ... am I missing something?

Comment: Taylor expansion of $1/z$ valid for $|z+1|>1$

Comment: I'll assume that this is impossible :)

Comment: @GRS Yes, $\;\frac1z\;$ is analytic in $\;|z+1|>1\;$ , yet $\;\frac1{z+1}\;$   is *not* so at $\;z=-1\;$ and can't thus be developed as a power series (Taylor or whatever) about this point...which would be like wanting to have a power series for $\;\frac1z\;$ about $\;z=0\;$ .

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot :)